# Google Sheets float numbers in .csv becoming dates in .xls

Tags: date, google-sheets, floating-point

Google Sheets currently does something rather obnoxious if you type a number such as `15.5` into a cell - it converts the number into `15/05/2020`

I have a sheet file with lots of prices filled in, but every now and then I see these dates pop up... I can't do arithmetics with those dates, and using the "format" command to turn them into money numbers yields crazy stuff, `43.966,00` for example (from the number above)

Is there a workaround for this?

- tl;dr - I need the floating point numbers which resemble dates to not become dates when inserted into a cell.

### edit:

I didn't include all the information at first, so here we go:

The issue is not only typing in values, I'm actually reading a .csv file and inserting it into sheets via python's pydrive.

The workaround must not be something manual, I'd like my numbers to "show up" correctly in sheets without further manipulating the file.

Comment: when you go to file>spreadsheet settings. what does it show for the locale of the sheet?

Comment: It says my locale - Brasil

Comment: Okay @Matt I realized I'm an idiot and if I turn the sheets' locale to say ```Japan``` _before_ the upload of the .csv, everything works wonders! So your solution gets the cake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Brasil sheets (because of Portuguese i assume) the comma is used as the decimal, not the period. So instead of writing 15.5 you need to write your numbers like 15,5

You can change that by changing the locale of the sheet to somewhere that uses traditional decimal points.